# Requesting Permission dialogue not showing up at all with this code, why?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I am trying to request STORAGE Permission from the user at runtime after clicking a certain button. But somehow, this code (which is contained within a fragment's class) is not working at all no matter what I try.

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    requestPermissions(this.requireActivity(), "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 392)
}
```

This piece of code isn't working either for both write and read permissions :

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.requireActivity(), "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 392)
}
```

No dialogue appears no matter what.

NOTE: I am testing on a physical device running on API 29.
NOTE2: I added the permission both WRITE and READ permissions to the manifest.
NOTE3: Performing any IO task crashes my app.

I looked up all over the internet but I still don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: can you confirm with an if condition that your app doesn't have the required permissions at runtime ? because it might be the problem with your IO tasks not with permissions

Comment: `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) `

Comment: by the way, if you're working on any api > 23 (android Marshmallow 6.0), it's not correct to assume that you have some permissions because you declared it in android manifest, sometimes if it's listed as dangerous you should still check if you have at runtime according to this  `If you declare any dangerous permissions, and if your app is installed on a device that runs Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, you must request the dangerous permissions at runtime by following the steps in this guide.`

Comment: which you can read about here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous_permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your way for checking the permissions if it's inside a fragment maybe it's not correct , since these methods are deprecated  and you may use another way which is the recommended one

> [Documentation for how to request permissions|android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission)

which is the right way which goes as this:

Step 1 -You put this code as global in fragment/activity:

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                if (isGranted) doSomething()
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't continue without the required permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
```

Step 2- Then when you need to request for a permission you call launch on the object you declared as global , which is to be called in the OnCreate() function of the Fragment / Activity .So if you want to ask these permissions at the creation of the fragment / Activity then just place this code in OnCreate() or if are using a button to check permission then set the onClickListener for the same in onCreate() function:

```
public void getNecessaryPermissionsAnddoSomething() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else doSomething();
    }
```

Comment: if you're requesting multiple permissions at the same time you can also use `ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions` instead of  `ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission`

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough responses! It seems that I have wrongly assumed that Permissions are granted just because there is no dialogue while the IO tasks were crashing my app. It seems that it was an entirely different problem. Thank you very much !

Comment: What was the problem?